# Serial port The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

My program is using 5 serial ports. My task is controlled by switches which feeds signal through serial port to start program. Among them, 4 are connected using FT4232 USB-232 converter. One which provides signal to start operation is connected using Prolific driver. I get the message "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request" in between the communication and even when I am not starting any operation and my program is idle although at idle condition I am not using serial port. During no-operation, I am not scanning ports in background to check port status.
This message appears in ports connected to FT4232 converter.

When I looked at the serial port in Device manager, it behaved as if the USB driver was removed and inserted. I have re-installed driver numerous times.

In my serial port event handler I have put all my codes inside try-catch block and there is no code to close serial ports [ serialPort.close() / serialPort.Dispose() ].

When I debug program using serial terminal (teraterminal and docklight), and not executing the windows forms program, the above mentioned problem does not arise.
The driver I installed is found on FTD website https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm.
The driver installation seems okay to me.[image]

Its mode is Asynchronous serial mode. (I think that is default mode).

I am not using FT4232 with any other MCUs. The FT4232 board contains MAX3232 IC.

The problem seems to lie in program. The error message appears whether or not serial port data exchange is taking place and its occurrence is erratic.
What is the reason for this behaviour ? How can I prevent it ?

Comment: Check Device Manager and see what driver is attached to each serial port.  Often error like this occur when the wrong USB to RS232 driver is installed.  You should always install the vendors USB to RS-232 driver and not the standard Microsoft driver or another vendors driver.  The hardware is designed to work only with the manufacturer driver.

Comment: I've been working with UARTs in PCs since the original 8080 PCs and have seen every type issue.  Also have done a lot of work with USB to RS-232 adapters.  I should be able to help solve issue.  What mode are you using the FT4232.  Just looked up the vendors data sheet and the chip has lots of modes.  Are you using a purchased board where chip is mounted?  Are you using a FPGA on board?  In device manager is the driver colored yellow (indicating a driver issue).

Comment: The driver is found from https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm. I am not using the ready made board with IC.

Comment: If you right click the Device Manager ports you should see the ftdi driver listed in the properties.  What cable do you use with device?  The handshaking (hardware/software should be off).  Do you have vendor application that you can check if the vendors tool give same symptoms?  Can you try with Putty or HyperTerminal?  First step is to make sure the issue is not your application.  Problem appears to be with the cable, or setup, or the hardware on your board, and not the c# code.

Comment: I checked the drivers installed and they seem okay . Handshaking is None.

Comment: What about cables?  Can you run with vendor code which will indicate the issue is not your code?  Right now I cannot tell if your code is bad or the hardware setup is bad.  I've solved lots of issues like this and the trick is to rule out what is working and what is not working one item at a time.